# Nesting in lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to fit a model in `lmer` with a factor which is nested in two other factors, as it occurs only in one combination of them.

Just for the record, I could fit it well in `lm` this way:

```r
model = lm(response ~ A * B * C + B * A / D, data = data)
```

So `D` is nested in both `A` and `B`. I get a good fit, with results that seems to in line with the data.

However, I also have a random factor nested in `A`, so I need to fit a mixed model:
The problem is when I try to do it in `lmer`, and I tried a few codes:

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + 
    (1 | A / random) + (1 | B / A / D), 
    data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> unable to evaluate scaled gradient
> 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
> 3: In as_lmerModLT(model, devfun) :
> Model may not have converged with 3 eigenvalues close to zero: 5.9e-10 -1.7e-09 -4.6e-09

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + (1 | B / A / D), data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> unable to evaluate scaled gradient
> 2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues
> 3: In as_lmerModLT(model, devfun) :
> Model may not have converged with 2 eigenvalues close to zero: -5.7e-10 -1.9e-09

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + 
   (1 | A : random) + (1 | B : A : D), 
   data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

This actually fits, but I can't get a p-value for D, as it treats it as a random factor.

I tried different ways to use "/", and it never fits.

I tried to check what is going on with the "/".
I removed all of the D types from the data, leaving only one of them, to keep the data balanced:

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + 
   (1 | A / random), data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

> Warning messages:
> 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
> Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
>
> - Rescale variables?
>   2: In as_lmerModLT(model, devfun) :
>   Model may not have converged with 1 eigenvalue close to zero: -1.2e-09

On the contrary, both these codes work fine, including the p-values which make sense:

```r
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + (1 | A : random), data = data, REML = TRUE)
model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + (1 | random), data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

So, is the problem being with the "/"?

Then, just to cross check, I used JMP, and I successfully fitted the desirable model for the response in which A B C are factors, D is a factor nested within B and A (in their interaction I think), and the `random` which is nested within A.
The results are also good and resemble the lm I showed before (not the same results exactly, guess because of the random).

Please, since it is working in lm and JMP, and a Statistician helped me to fit this model, don't recommend me to try Cross Validated, since it's not an issue of the model I want to build.
I believe I fail to translate for R what I want.

Overall, I think the issue is a syntax error because of the `/`.
I don't mind using the `:` if it is correct, but it not useful for getting estimates and p-value for the D factor...

It is important for me to do it in R.
Any correct way to write this code?

Here is my data set:

```r
text <- "random C   B   A   D   response
1   C1  B2  A1  -   3.111699659
2   C1  B1  A1  -   2.205213087
1   C1  B1  A1  -   2.256139401
3   C1  B2  A2  D1  2.491588734
2   C1  B2  A1  -   3.369929048
4   C1  B2  A2  D1  2.134408505
4   C1  B1  A2  -   1.680044451
4   C1  B2  A2  D2  3.138216142
5   C1  B2  A2  D1  2.473153065
5   C1  B1  A2  -   1.594518315
7   C1  B2  A1  -   3.579612749
3   C1  B1  A2  -   1.746472494
3   C1  B2  A2  D2  2.75206018
6   C1  B2  A2  D2  3.91349241
7   C1  B1  A1  -   2.249988368
6   C1  B2  A2  D1  2.651348028
8   C1  B2  A1  -   3.159486466
5   C1  B2  A2  D2  3.725889875
6   C1  B1  A2  -   1.831991493
8   C1  B1  A1  -   2.117377054
9   C1  B2  A2  D2  3.281653001
9   C1  B2  A2  D1  2.610483725
9   C1  B1  A2  -   1.767116785
10  C1  B2  A1  -   3.475305093
10  C1  B1  A1  -   1.984320741
1   C2  B2  A1  -   3.2046148
2   C2  B1  A1  -   2.111525363
1   C2  B1  A1  -   1.920365596
3   C2  B2  A2  D1  2.547025458
2   C2  B2  A1  -   2.995976245
4   C2  B2  A2  D1  2.388871111
4   C2  B1  A2  -   1.393936579
4   C2  B2  A2  D2  3.26200647
5   C2  B2  A2  D1  3.168510446
5   C2  B1  A2  -   2.29951629
7   C2  B2  A1  -   3.130715219
3   C2  B1  A2  -   1.556548674
3   C2  B2  A2  D2  3.076660317
6   C2  B2  A2  D2  3.486158226
7   C2  B1  A1  -   1.742174979
6   C2  B2  A2  D1  3.149312249
8   C2  B2  A1  -   2.976372068
5   C2  B2  A2  D2  3.617198525
6   C2  B1  A2  -   1.225995726
8   C2  B1  A1  -   2.034857766
9   C2  B2  A2  D2  3.053560499
9   C2  B2  A2  D1  1.894313162
9   C2  B1  A2  -   1.459949378
10  C2  B2  A1  -   3.155808502
10  C2  B1  A1  -   1.786492784
1   C3  B2  A1  -   2.293992477
2   C3  B1  A1  -   1.888853885
1   C3  B1  A1  -   1.946907828
3   C3  B2  A2  D1  2.398367521
2   C3  B2  A1  -   3.107024555
4   C3  B2  A2  D1  2.666788138
4   C3  B1  A2  -   1.646395286
4   C3  B2  A2  D2  3.009837387
5   C3  B2  A2  D1  3.491289359
5   C3  B1  A2  -   1.254967299
7   C3  B2  A1  -   3.220482741
3   C3  B1  A2  -   1.152944661
3   C3  B2  A2  D2  3.278597685
6   C3  B2  A2  D2  3.127304762
7   C3  B1  A1  -   1.917848059
6   C3  B2  A2  D1  2.933899276
8   C3  B2  A1  -   3.195523263
5   C3  B2  A2  D2  3.338612994
6   C3  B1  A2  -   1.634269268
8   C3  B1  A1  -   1.70054355
9   C3  B2  A2  D2  3.433294049
9   C3  B2  A2  D1  2.819881815
9   C3  B1  A2  -   0
10  C3  B2  A1  -   3.546624416
10  C3  B1  A1  -   1.951522539"
data <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\s+"))
n_cols <- length(data) / 6
df <- data.frame(matrix(data, nrow = n_cols, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(df) <- df[1, ]
df <- df[-1, ]
df
```

the results in JMP for a parallel model <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + A:B:D + (1 | A : random), data = data, REML = TRUE)

```r
Parameter estimates
Term                Estimate    Std Error   DFDen   t Ratio Prob>|t|
Intercept           2.4039809   0.057877    9.522   41.54   <.0001
C[C1]               0.1317872   0.053587    54.92   2.46    0.0171
C[C3]               -0.118639   0.053587    54.92    -2.21  0.0310
B[B2]               0.6686877   0.037892    54.92   17.65   <.0001
C[C1]*B[B2]         -0.076238   0.053587    54.92    -1.42  0.1605
C[C3]*B[B2]         0.1072289   0.053587    54.92   2.00    0.0503
A[A2]               -0.173929   0.057877    9.522    -3.01  0.0139
C[C1]*A[A2]         -0.04121    0.053587    54.92    -0.77  0.4452
C[C3]*A[A2]         -0.017662   0.053587    54.92    -0.33  0.7430
B[B2]*A[A2]         0.0783865   0.037892    54.92   2.07    0.0433
C[C1]*B[B2]*A[A2]       -0.074236   0.053587    54.92    -1.39  0.1715
C[C3]*B[B2]*A[A2]       0.1017329   0.053587    54.92   1.90    0.0629
B[B2]:A[A2]:D[D1]       -0.32251    0.057287    54.92    -5.63  <.0001

fixed effect tests
Source      Nparm   DF  DFDen   F Ratio     Prob > F
C       2   2   54.92   3.6700      0.0319
B       1   1   54.92   311.4309    <.0001
C*B     2   2   54.92   2.1209      0.1296
A       1   1   9.522   9.0309      0.0139
C*A     2   2   54.92   0.6357      0.5334
B*A     1   1   54.92   4.2795      0.0433
C*B*A       2   2   54.92   1.9289      0.1550
D[B,A]      1   1   54.92   31.6942     <.0001

fixed effect tests after removing C*B*A, C*A
Source      Nparm   DF  DFDen   F Ratio     Prob > F
C       2   2   58.94   2.8276      0.0672
B       1   1   58.94   305.1555    <.0001
C*B     2   2   58.94   2.9235      0.0616
A       1   1   9.555   9.0051      0.0140
B*A     1   1   58.94   4.1933      0.0450
D[B,A]      1   1   58.94   31.0555     <.0001
```

Comment: In case you don't know: `~ (1 | a / b)` gets expanded to `~ (1 | a) + (1 | b : a)`. Check out `lme4::findbars(~ (1 | a / b))`. What exactly is the `random` variable? Can you confirm it is a factor variable? How many levels does each of your variables have? It would be helpful to see plots of the data. Ideally, you would provide the data.

Comment: There are 2 levels for A B D, making 5 possible combinations (treatments) of them (since D is nested in a certain combination of A and B).
Factor C has 3 levels.
the random is a factor with 10 levels, which relates each treatment through C, but also between samples, and is nested within A.

Comment: So it looks like this:

random1: A2B1D-, A2B2D1, A2B2D2
random2: A1B1D-, A1B2D-
random3: A2B1D-, A2B2D1, A2B2D2
random4: A1B1D-, A1B2D-
random5: A2B1D-, A2B2D1, A2B2D2
random6: A1B1D-, A1B2D-
random7: A2B1D-, A2B2D1, A2B2D2
random8: A1B1D-, A1B2D-
random9: A2B1D-, A2B2D1, A2B2D2
random10: A1B1D-, A1B2D-

All are repeated through C1-3, so I have 75 samples

Comment: Variables with two categories are not sufficient to estimate a random effect variance. Thus, (1 | A : random) works fine because that’s 30 groups but (1 | A) + (1 | random : A) is not fine because it tries to estimate a variance based on two groups.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that I should use (1 | A : random). I need to clarify that actually D has three levels: 1, 2 and "-". For me, when I see the results, I know that "-" is irrelevant. Is there any way to nest in lmer without making the nested factor a random effect? If not, is there any other function that could provide a solution for me? The lm for example did result in something...

Comment: Maybe didn’t express myself well. I’m trying to say that your data doesn’t support the model well. If the model fit converges in such a case depends strongly on the optimizer and the starting values and false convergence can easily occur. Have you read help(“convergence”)? I would be wary of any model fit that is based on that few observed subjects.

Comment: Thanks Ronland. From your statement I just understand that I could nest a factor which is not a random in lme... :) but I do get this message: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 21 columns / coefficients - I hope its still ok

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `B*A` in your first formula is interpreted as `(B*A)/D`, either

```r
response ~ A * B * C + (1|B : A : D) + (1|A : random)
```

or

```r
response ~ A * B * C + B : A : D + (1| A : random)
```

would be the best choices.

You said you tried the first, but don't want `D` treated as a grouping variable: you *could* get an approximate p-value using a likelihood ratio test (i.e. comparing to a model without the `(1|B:A:D)` term), or a more accurate p-value by using the parametric bootstrapping methods in the `pbkrtest` package (but, you can't get p-values for particular levels/contrasts of `D` ...)

As @Roland suggested, since `A/B` expands to `A + A:B` and `A*B` expands to `A + B + A:B` in R's model formula language, it's easy to include effects twice in your model if you're not careful. R is generally careful about dropping redundant terms automatically, but there are two issues described above that will give you a little trouble.

- it sounds like `D` occurs only in one combination of `A` and `B`. However, when you include the three way `A:B:D` interaction (either explicitly or by writing `(A*B)/D`, R will try to add a coefficient for *all* combinations of `A`, `B`, `D`. If you look at the coefficients (`coef()`) for your linear model, you should see a bunch of `NA` values for the non-existent combinations. That doesn't necessarily cause trouble ...
- when you run `lmer` with the same fixed-effect component, it does the same thing but is noisier ("fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 21 columns / coefficients", as you saw)
- if you have a model that has both a main effect of `A` in both the fixed component (explicitly or implicitly in a term such as `A*B*C`) and the random component (explicitly or implicitly in a term such as `(1|A/random)`, you'll run into trouble because R can't automatically detect that you're trying to fit the same component in two different places in the model.

---

When I run the code with your data provided above, I get reasonable answers. The computed denominator df are similar, and large, whether I use the "Satterthwaite" or "Kenward-Roger" option (approximately 55 in either case; >= 50 is the usual cutoff for "you can probably ignore ddf altogether and use a Z-test rather than a t-test"). Differences you're seeing between JMP and R *might* be due to differences in default choice of contrasts ...

```r
df <- read.table(text = text, header = TRUE)
library(lmerTest)
m1 <- lmer(response ~ A * B * C + B : A : D + (1| A : random),
           df)

options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
printCoefmat(coef(summary(m1, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")), digits = 3)
## printCoefmat(coef(summary(m1, ddf = "Satterthwaite")), digits = 3)
```

```
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.16261    0.15336 51.94526   14.10  < 2e-16 ***
AA2         -0.43858    0.21688 51.94526   -2.02    0.048 *  
BB2          1.17660    0.19845 54.05518    5.93  2.2e-07 ***
CC2         -0.24352    0.19845 54.05518   -1.23    0.225    
CC3         -0.28147    0.19845 54.05518   -1.42    0.162    
AA2:BB2      0.33911    0.26870 54.05518    1.26    0.212    
AA2:CC2      0.10669    0.28065 54.05518    0.38    0.705    
AA2:CC3     -0.30484    0.28065 54.05518   -1.09    0.282    
BB2:CC2     -0.00298    0.28065 54.05518   -0.01    0.992    
BB2:CC3      0.01500    0.28065 54.05518    0.05    0.958    
AA2:BB2:CC2  0.18696    0.37126 54.05518    0.50    0.617    
AA2:BB2:CC3  0.70388    0.37126 54.05518    1.90    0.063 .  
AA2:BB2:DD1 -0.64502    0.11457 54.05518   -5.63  6.6e-07 ***
```

Without looking, I can't tell what you mean that JMP's p-values "[make] more sense" ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben, for explaining and confirming... both "response ~ A * B * C + B : A : D + (1| A : random)" or "response ~ A * B * C + (B * A) / D + (1| A : random)" are fine, as I get only 7 coefficients dropped. The problem now is that the df are not integers, guess because of the dropping, and so the p-values are not the same as in JMP... Is there anything to do to correct this? in JMP the syntax for the nesting is "D[A,B]"

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could give a [mcve], but the short answer is that computing the degrees of freedom for mixed models is complicated. See e.g. [the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have). If JMP gives you integer df for an unbalanced design, that means it's using a different (and quite possibly inferior) method of approximating the df. How big are the differences in df, and the resulting p-values?

Comment: Actually, I noticed the df in JMP are non-integer as well: Both in parameter estimates and fixed effect test, the intercept (not in the fixed effect) and A get a dfden of 9.522, while the rest 54.92. In R, lmer(response ~ A * B * C + B : A : D + (1| A : random)), in the estimates, the intercept gets a df of 39.68, A gets 46.68, and the rest 54.84. in the fixed effect the dendf is 10.48 for A, and 54,84 for the rest. The p-values are different, with JMP's making a bit more sense. I edited my original post to add a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your effort! It helps a lot. In JMP, When I remove insignificant interactions in JMP, C:B becomes almost significant (I added details in the main post), and in post-hoc I find the results to represent a process that should happen, this is what I mean by saying "makes more sense". On the contrary, removing the same interactions in R does not changes the p-value of B:C that much. So I was wondering how to reproduce these results in R, if I could even consider them better...

Comment: for getting fixed effect tests in R I use anova(model), or now anova(model, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")

Comment: You might try `car::Anova()` as well/instead.